# Naming Conventions or Directory Strucure

Tags: java, php, naming, convention

I'm PHP programmer, but what I want to discuss is influenced by Java.

After read some articles about Hungarian Notation and Naming Conventions of several Languages, I proved how clear are the Java's Naming Convention for Interfaces, I have one question.

Considering the Object Collections' case, where we have an Abstract Class called **AbstractCollection** and the concrete class called **Lists**, how should I name an **Interface** for **Lists**?

The question is, in Java's Naming Conventions, there is no prefix nor suffix for Interfaces, such as **ListsInterface** or **InterfaceLists**.

**Lists** IS an Interface name and, obviously, at least in PHP, two files in same directory cannot have the same name of a class or interface.

Not EVERY class needs an Interface, I know, but what if I decide to move to a programming team? The other programmers may use my classes, but they should not open the class files to see what public methods it offers.

Just by reading its Interface, everything is clear.

The Directory Structure point came from the possibility to add a subdirectory with the same name of the Interface and, inside it, the concrete class' file. E.g.:

```
/  
/Collections  
/Collections/Lists.php <-- Interface  
/Colection/Lists/Lists.php <--- Concrete Class
```

What now?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't give an interface and a class the same name. Never. For your readers sake.

I think your particular problem has little to do with convention, but with a concrete naming problem `Lists` doesn't sound like an interface at all. `List` does. But in that case an implementing class would have a more concrete name, like `List_DoublyLinked` and `List_SinglyLinked` (or whatever kind of list you are talking about).

Comment: I know that. But I think it would be the opposite. Lists (plural) represent the Interface because everything implementing it will be a single List (singular). Particularly I don't like these ClassesWithVeryLongName :P

Comment: @BrunoAugusto ClassesWithVeryLongNames are a good thing. They are descriptive. If you are using namespaced code you can still reference them using shorter names in your code, by defining aliases ;)

Comment: Side-note for tumbleweeds rolling by like me -- using the literal name `List` to identify any definition will fail out due to the reservation of the word "list"; rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check PHP naming conventions instead of Java.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

Zend provides a good one, nearly considering all the cases.

Symfony has another ( http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToContributeToSymfony#CodingStandards ), Pear has another ( http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php ) too.

In your case just to show that an interface is an interface, Zend forces you to put a suffix on your interafces. So your dir structure should be like:

```
Collections/
Collections/ListsInterface.php
Collections/Lists/ListAbstract.php
Collections/Lists/MyList.php
```

I don't know if this post answers your question but I hope that it helps.

Comment: In the last days I read about several Naming Conventions and Java's was the most elegant I could find.  I'm trying to avoid such prefixes (or suffixes) but I have no luck so far. :(